# Optional Parameters -- POST Request in php

Tags: php, optional-parameters

I'm working on a client-server app for a client of mine. I was asked to add a few more columns to the db. I'm updated the php endpoint to handle this. The issue I am running into is that not all client apps will be updated right away, so how can I make the additional parameters optional? I'm quite new to php, so my apologies if I don't understand right away.

**EDIT:** the thing is data might not even contain the three optional members. So I need to check whether or not that data has the members devicemake, devicemodel, or networktype.

Sample code:

```
switch(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']))
{
    case 'get':
        echo"this is a get request";
        $data = $_GET;
        print_r($data);
        $problem = $data['problem'];
        $environment = $data['environment'];
        $latitude = $data['latitude'];
        $longitude = $data['longitude'];
        $devicemake = ($data['devicemake'] ? $data['devicemake'] : null); // optional
        $devicemodel = ($data['devicemodel'] ? $data['devicemodel'] : null);  //optional
        $networktype = ($data['networktype'] ? $data['networktype'] : null); // optional
        $additionalinfo = $data['additionalinfo'];

        break;
    case 'post':
        echo "this is a post request";
        print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS);
        $postvars = $HTTP_POST_VARS;
        $data = json_decode($postvars);

        $problem = $data->problem;
        $environment = $data->environment;
        $latitude = $data->latitude;
        $longitude = $data->longitude;
        $devicemake = ($data->devicemake ? $data->devicemake : null);  //optional
        $devicemodel = ($data->devicemodel ? $data->devicemodel : null);  //optional
        $networktype = ($data->networktype ? $data->networktype : null);  //optional
        $additionalinfo = $data->additionalinfo;

        break;
}
```

Comment: You should test with `isset($data['devicemake'])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$additionalinfo = isset($data['additionalinfo']) ? $data['additionalinfo'] : "not set";
```

What the above does is basically run an 'if' statement on `isset();`

`isset()` does exactly what it says - returns true / false for if the item in the parenthesis 'is set' or 'has been initialised'

The `"not set"` is whatever you want to do if it isn't set (the `else{}` part of an if statement)

**edit** just saw the optional bits sorry -

```
    $devicemake = isset($data->devicemake) ? $data->devicemake : null;  //optional
    $devicemodel = isset($data->devicemodel) ? $data->devicemodel : null;  //optional
    $networktype = isset($data->networktype) ? $data->networktype : null;
```

I will leave the rest of the explanation above the edit as I hadn't seen that bit and it may be useful for someone else.